# App upload to itunesConnect fails due to 'invalid Binary' but the mail from apple does not mention any issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to publish my app to itunesConnect. Everything goes well and I successfully upload the app. After sometime I receive a notification from itunesConnect saying "Invalid Binary" and I receive a mail from Apple

> App Store Connect
>
> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, > "App Name here". Please correct the following issues, then upload 
>   again.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

There are no issues mentioned in the mail.

I have already tried revoking all the certificates and created new certificates. I have tried manual code signing and automatic code signing. I have also tried uploading the app using both Xcode and Application loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. I finally could send the app to review by changing:

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to a long and a better description about why are we requesting that permission.
(Same for `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`) and other privacy permission usage.

I had "Advertising" as string before, and it seems that is not describing clearly the purpose about requesting the device Location data to the user, at the end the binary processed and we are on **Waiting for review** state.

I hope this helps to you.

Comment: Damn. I have the same "Advertising" string. What did you use? We are not using location in our app but some of the SDKs are using.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! For us it was `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` which needs to have a longer text as well. Even though we had a full sentence already...